# Blur and vibrancy effects on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I just don't know how to do that. I've tried everything from Stackoverflow and nothing worked. I have a view, image and below all of that tableView in my hierarchy. But table view is still white. Is there somebody who knows how to do this? As I wrote, nothing from here worked.

I want to have this kind of UITableView:

[image: UITableView]

Navigation bar is part of my question too (his blur and vibrancy).

After use of this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background3.png"))

    cell.backgroundView = backgroundImageView

    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView

    visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height)

    backgroundImageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.field[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

My tableView now look like this:

[image: simulator screenshot]

And that is logical, because it is the look of the background3.png image.

Comment: I'm getting tired of the cowards down voting questions without having to give a reason or their name.  there's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So the solution is really simple. I've find a great tutorial on Youtube:

[Swift iOS tutorial - Custom tableview appearance in Xcode 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K-83AJYgho&list=PLAhicyLvj6Ipvj8g_w7lmjWkfWIUFjVmT&index=10)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    var openSansSemibold = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 12)?.fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.TraitBold)
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(descriptor: openSansSemibold!, size: 12)

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return cell
}
```

In viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 70
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background"))
```

And that is it. Every odd cell has clear color, every even has blurred background. It looks really great!

Comment: You're just setting the alpha...you are not applying any blur here at all. See my answer for details of how to use the UIVibrancyEffect class, which is the elephant in the room.

Comment: Also, your setting every other cell, which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: Also you are using font descriptors to extract a semi bold font that is already semi bold...

Comment: Also, most of this code is not necessary to make your point, and is specific to your view hierarchy and not the OP's.

Answer (score 9):

Subclass UITableViewController.

```
let effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
let resizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
```

Build a background view like this and stick it into your table view. Notice separator effect, which is new api.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
    backgroundView.autoresizingMask = resizingMask
    backgroundView.addSubview(self.buildImageView())
    backgroundView.addSubview(self.buildBlurView())

    tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: effect)
}

func buildImageView() -> UIImageView {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "coolimage"))
    imageView.frame = view.bounds
    imageView.autoresizingMask = resizingMask
    return imageView
}

func buildBlurView() -> UIVisualEffectView {
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
    blurView.frame = view.bounds
    blurView.autoresizingMask = resizingMask
    return blurView
}
```

Change background colour of cell to clear, so background is visible when you have cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! UITableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is Stackoverflow. I've found a solution for my own question and somebody had downvoted me :-D

Comment: This is working. But you have to update resizingMask line for Swift 2.0, I upvoted this thank you :)

Comment: No you got it wrong. I suggested edit for this answer, I was fix it for Swift 2.0 , your current code is returning compiler error on Swift 2.0

Comment: Swift 2.0 syntax: `let resizingMask: UIViewAutoresizing = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]`